# .pch File in Xcode 6.1

Tags: ios, xcode, header, pch

I have looked all over and cannot find a solution to this problem.

The problem involves adding a header file to an xcode 6.1 project. What I want to be able to do is add a header file that is automatically imported to each of the files I create.

i.e.

I create a.h & a.m.

Where previouslyMade.pch or previouslyMade.h definitions are already included.

I've looked through build settings and there isn't an option to update the .pch file.

Is there a solution to this or have I got to import a .h file every time I make a new file?

Thanks

Comment: Chris can you clarify your question a little bit more please.Build "Settings -> Prefix Header" is the place where you specify your .pch.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You'll need to create a PCH file named `ProjectName-Prefix.pch`. In the new file dialog you'll find PCH under Other.
2. Go to `Project > Build Settings` and search "Prefix Header". Under "Apple LLVM 6.0 - Language" add your PCH file: `ProjectName/ProjectName-Prefix.pch` note: make sure you select 'All' not 'Basic'
3. Now add any headers you want globally included in your PCH file
4. Clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: Hi, see the image [here](http://imgur.com/n3wEsFM). When I search for prefix header in build settings, there are no hits

Comment: @Chris, select the "All" tab instead of "Basic".

Comment: Thanks! Just what I needed :) I've adjusted the answer a tiny bit to make it clearer for others in the future! Thanks again!